# I want to listen udp broadcast packets from server to my App on button click on port 5000

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Android: I want my app to listen to udp broadcast `datagram` packets from the server on `port number` `5000` and `5002` from `AsyncTask` class on button click i.e in mainactivity, click button1 to listen incoming udp packets on `port` `5000` and click button2 to listen udp packets on port `5002`.

This code may contain many errors, if you have working code that capture datagrams on any port number that would help me without using any ip address.

```
 public class AsyncTask<parameters> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            final int PORT =5000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramSocket socket= new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            buffer = packet.getData();
            System.out.println("Received: "+new String(buffer));

        } catch (Io Exception e) {
            // TO DO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: are client and server in the same LAN?

Comment: Use Serivice instead of AsyncTask